# How to use Matlab built-in color schemes with R?

Tags: r, matlab, color-scheme

I am working on image processing in R. At present I am working with the default color schemes  (topo, terrain, rainbow, heat, cm). But, I would like to use the color schemes provided by Matlab (specifically the black to yellow color scheme - Hot) with R. Is there a way to use these color schemes in R? I used the OOMPA package which includes additional color schemes ([http://bioinformatics.mdanderson.org/Software/OOMPA/ClassDiscovery/html/colorSchemes.html](https://bioinformatics.mdanderson.org/Software/OOMPA/ClassDiscovery/html/colorSchemes.html)) for R to use with biological images, but this did not solve the purpose.

[image: Matlab color scheme]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.de](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/ref/colormap-dropdown.gif))</sub>

Comment: See ?colorRampPalette for a general approach to building these. Jet is in the examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
install.packages("dcemriS4", dependencies=TRUE)
library(dcemriS4)
hotmetal(10) 
image(outer(1:20,1:20,"+"), col=hotmetal(75), main="hotmetal")
```

[image]

In the interest of teaching newbies "how to fish" I will admit that I didn't know this in advance and that what I did was:

```
install.packages("sos") # which I consider to essential in ones R tool chest of search strategies 
library(sos) # actually it's in my .Rprofile
findFn("color matlab hot")
```

It found `dcemri` http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/dcemri/html/hotmetal.html

I only found `library(dcemriS4)` in current packages so I loaded it and gave it a shot with the code in the older package help page ... with success.

Answer (score 4):

```
?colorRampPalette

plot(1:20, pch = 19, cex = 5, 
     col = colorRampPalette(c('black','red','yellow','white'))(20))
```

[image]